# error Sub Main() in aplication.run(new form1) for logout

Tags: vb.net, winforms, logout

I have the following

Code Sub Main()

```
'Inicia si el loggin fue correcto
If FormLogin.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Yes Then
    Try
        Application.Run(New Form1)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox...
    End Try
Else
    Application.Exit()
End If
```

For Close Form1 and show FormLogin

```
Dispose()
Close()
FormLogin.ShowDialog()
```

an error occurs to the Application.Run, it is a matter of closing the current process, or that Form1 cannot be closed because it is the main form:

```
 Application.Run(New Form1)
```

I start Form1 as main form, then close Form1 to show FormLogin and start again.

what should I do?

Comment: "an error occurs" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: Switch the order of Dispose and Close

Comment: I could be mistaken, however when the code attempts to execute the line… `Application.Run(New Form1)` … you will most likely get an error stating that… _”Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.”_ … the error is fairly clear and it bears the question… “Do you need to start a second thread”? … Or… Is there some reason you need to run the other form under a second thread? Is there some reason… `Me.Hide()` … `Dim f2 = New Form2()` … and … `f2.ShowDialog()` … `Me.Visible = True` will not accomplish what you need?

Comment: Instead of passing Form1 or FormLogin to `Application.Run()`, derive your own custom class from [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), then pass an instance of that to `Application.Run()`.  This will allow you to open and close your forms as many times as you want without the application closing on you when you close one of the forms.  The app would be tied to your instance of ApplicationContext and it'd only exit when you explicitly call `Application.Exit()` from your class code.